# Is there anything I can do to simplify this even further?

Tags: voltage, current

I feel like there is something more I can do, especially with the current source.

The voltage in the voltage source is 4.024 V, and the resistor is 2556 ohms.

[image]

Comment: It would help if you could explain what the *purpose* of this is.  You've constructed something that is mostly self consistent, but truly odd.  It's hard to suggest how you could "simplify" it without knowing the goal.   Absent a goal, one might as well just simplify one of the sources out of it entirely, or given that it doesn't do anything "simplify" to a blank sheet of paper.  Help us help you by explaining the purpose of the exercise.

Answer (score 3):

You can remove the current source because it is short-circuited.

The Earth symbol should always be drawn pointing down. It represents metal plates buried in the ground (not in the sky).

Comment: NB: the downwards ground orientation also applies to Australien engineers, by convention.